How can I add a DragGesture to a sub-view of TabView while still making sure that sub-views inside TabView are scrollable?
I have added a DragGesture to each Image which works as expected and prints "sub-view drag worked." but now, swiping
between views of the TabView doesn't works anymore.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SliderView()
    }
}

struct SliderView: View {
    let images = ["image1", "image2", "image3", "image4", "image5"]
    @State private var selectedTab = 2

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) {
                    Image("\(images[$0])")
                        .resizable()
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .tag($0)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    if value.translation.height > 50 {
                                        print("sub-view drag worked.")
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}


The drag gesture intercepts the swipe gesture, which itself is effectively just a drag gesture too. You didn't describe, how you expect both to be able to work together and it is hard to see how they can.
However, one possibility would be to restrict the drag gesture to a particular area of the screen, perhaps the central area:

if the drag gesture begins in the central area, it is interpreted by your gesture handler
otherwise, if the gesture begins at the side or the top of the screen, it is interpreted by the TabView.

Here is an updated version of your example which works this way.

An almost-transparent overlay is applied over the image, with padding of 50pt on all sides.
Since the images are being scaled-to-fill, it is necessary to use a GeometryReader to measure the screen dimensions, so that the images can be clipped to the frame size.

GeometryReader { proxy in
    TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
        ForEach(images.indices, id: \.self) {
            Image("\(images[$0])")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
                .clipped()
                .overlay {
                    Color.black
                        .opacity(0.001)
                        .gesture(
                            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                                .onEnded { value in
                                    if value.translation.height > 50 {
                                        print("sub-view drag worked.")
                                    }
                                }
                        )
                        .padding(50)
                }
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                .tag($0)
        }
    }
    .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .always))
}
.ignoresSafeArea()

If you would like to see the area covered by the overlay, change the opacity from 0.001 to 0.1. I have done that for the screen recording below:


EDIT If the overlay has equal padding on all sides, then a simpler way of achieving the same thing is to apply a .contentShape with a large .inset:
Image("\(images[$0])")
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: proxy.size.width, height: proxy.size.height)
    .clipped()
    .contentShape(Rectangle().inset(by: 50)) //  HERE
    .gesture(
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: 3.0, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onEnded { value in
                if value.translation.height > 50 {
                    print("sub-view drag worked.")
                }
            }
    )
    .ignoresSafeArea()
    .tag($0)


thanks this one worked. One other way I found was by increasing "minimumDistance" to 30.0
This way when user swipes horizontally, it will trigger the swipe / drag gesture but when user swipes vertically by distance of atleast 30.0, then sub-view drag gesture will be activated instead.

Answer updated to show how a content shape with a large inset can also be used
